# How much autonomy does the Israeli Army have from the War Cabinet?

Tags: armed-conflict, military, israel

> The announcement followed remarks by US Secretary of State Antony
> Blinken, from Amman, that Israel would soon announce the beginning of
> the third phase. **This suggests that Washington has begun to coordinate
> exclusively with the Israeli army to bypass Netanyahu and the need for
> the war cabinet’s approval.** This explains why it was the army command,
> and not the prime minister, who made the announcement.

https://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/50/1203/515390/AlAhram-Weekly/World/Israeli-war-cabinet-Imminent-collapse.aspx

How much autonomy does the Israeli Army have from the War Cabinet? Is there a legal obligation for the Israel army to do everything as the War Cabinet demands? I am asking because it appears that the army is bypassing the cabinet to coordinate with the U.S. army directly. I am wondering if the army has enough autonomy to carry out what it deems necessary without needing to receive approval from the War Cabinet.

Comment: Armies get high level goals from civilians (in this case the war cabinet) and may coordinate with other armies (in this case the US) on technical details to obtain those goals. This does not mean they are bypassing the civilian leadership.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question:
>
> How much autonomy does the Israeli Army have from the War Cabinet?

Depends upon what you mean by autonomy.  The IDF is answerable to and entirely dependent on the War Cabinet?  If the IDF were "coordinating" with the US State Dept, which isn't out of the question, you can be pretty positive it wouldn't be "exclusively", nor without the full support of the civilian government most especially the war Cabinet.